# RPC failed; result=28, HTTP code = 0

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to push my code into github, but almost everytime I meet this error

```
error: RPC failed; result=28, HTTP code = 0
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

It's so annoying. Anyone knows how to fix this?

**Update** After I googled, I read that running `git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000` could solve the problem. But even after I ran that command, I still met the problem.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use git:// or git+ssh://, not https

Comment: Nice. This works. I used the https because for some reasons the ssh couldn't work with my office proxy. The error above only happened when I was working at my house.
Since the remote url could be easily switched from git to https vice versa, this solution is great.
Thanks.

Comment: Is there any explanation why the error happened with the https url?

Comment: Sorry, nothing found from github boys, but trouble traced long time to the past with singe recipe to fix

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to use SSH here as mentioned in the accepted answer. Recently got stuck with the same issue. Increase the Http default 1 MiB buffer size to a large value:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000
```

then try `git push remote branch_name`.

Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem( working behind a proxy and not able to access git://)

maybe it depends on the network situation?

do the "push" more times and it works for me. 
(pushed total 5 times, 2 successful)

btw, I am using the "https_proxy" environment variable, not the "http_proxy"

Answer (score 0):

That error code is a timeout error on the client.  Although I suspect that the server-side is closing as the message suggests.  To try and get more information you could try setting the environment variable `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` for your push eg:

`GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git push origin`

This can give you an indication of whether it is the client timing out or the server disconnecting that is the original error.  There are a number of things you might do to ensure that you're not always coming across this error.

1. Check the timeouts on the server side, if you can control it.  They may be too small. This depends on the server implementation.
2. Check your repository for large files particularly binary files.  These can be handled differently.
3. Ensure you aren't setting http.lowSpeedLimit, http.lowSpeedTime inadvertently: they should be off by default (by looking at the code).

**Large Repository**

For point 2. There are a number of things you can do if you suspect that the pack you are pushing is large objects.  This blog post is quite detailed on the subject:

http://blogs.atlassian.com/2014/05/handle-big-repositories-git/

I don't think the http.postBuffer is really a solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Generally these error conditions and codes are due to a network misconfiguration or unreliable internet connectivity at the moment. Usually after a few tries, everything should be back to normal. Try different connection protocols if problem persists after several tries.