# Git: error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 411

Tags: git, github, runtime-error

**Symptoms:**

Git suddenly refused to push a repository (to github in my case):

```
$ git push
Counting objects: 9292, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2136/2136), done.
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 411
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Writing objects: 100% (8222/8222), 1.27 MiB | 837 KiB/s, done.
Total 8222 (delta 6060), reused 8181 (delta 6033)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [git push fails: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 411](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651749/git-push-fails-rpc-failed-result-22-http-code-411)

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Here is what helped, the following command increases git buffer to 500mb:

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

Comment: +1 for posting a helpful self-answer. ProjectLocker had been working well for me for weeks, then suddenly I was getting this message. This answer worked for me.

Comment: how did you figure out the problem is about the buffer? Thank you !This also sovle my problem!

Comment: do changes to git config apply directly without any restart?

Comment: Yes, right away. You can also specify a `--global` option for some variables to be shared across the system.

Comment: @Jaskey I'm guessing he realized an HTTP 411 code is a 'content length required' error and decided to try changing the buffer size. I had this problem too, so I'm just guessing.