# Unexpected response when cloning using git

Tags: git

Today I wanted to clone the repository scipy using git clone. But I got a unexpected response.

```
git clone https://github.com/scipy/scipy.git scipy
Cloning into 'scipy'...
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 500
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I don't know what happened and need some help.

Comment: That is a big repository running at around `40 MB`. Does this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16557072/1860929 help?

Comment: Also check this thread https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/4437