# Configure egit http.postbuffer for large push

Tags: eclipse, git

I'm using **Egit** and when trying to push a large commit i get the following:

> RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 411

looking that up brings me to this page:
[Git: error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 411](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16557071/git-error-rpc-failed-result-22-http-code-411)

where the answer is to run:

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

How do I configure this parameter in EGit? (Eclipse git)

Comment: Did you try adding that in Eclipse? `Repository (right click) -> Properties->Add Entry`.