# Git clone return result=18 code=200 on a specific repository

Tags: git, git-config

I'm trying to clone a internal repository from our company repository, and I keep getting this error:

```
error: RPC failed; result=18, HTTP code = 200
```

It always happens only after the repository have been completely downloaded (It takes a while).

I've tried using torotiseGit. Here is the report:

```
git.exe clone   --progress -v  "http://path/repository.git" "C:\Users\user\Documents\code\repository"

Cloning into 'C:\Users\user\Documents\code\repository'...
POST git-upload-pack (424 bytes)
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4895/4895)   
Receiving objects: 100% (6970/6970), 61.89 MiB | 4.82 MiB/s
Resolving deltas: 100% (2610/2610)
Resolving deltas: 100% (2610/2610), done.
remote: Total 6970 (delta 2610), reused 5702 (delta 1672)
error: RPC failed; result=18, HTTP code = 200

git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128)
```

I've tried several times, from a Linux machine and from a windows machine. Same error

How can i further investigate the error?
I couldn't find any useful information on Google

EDIT: I've checked the Apache logs on the Git server - There is a GET and a POST (with result 200) corresponding to each clone. The POST is a bit big (60MB) - So I've tried increasing the postBuffer to 500MB, but the error still occurs

Could this really be a git bug?

I wish it gave more informative errors...

Comment: does it work for some other user/connectivity type?

Comment: Especially check if using ssh instead of http works (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700824/rpc-failed-result-28-http-code-0 )

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Other users download this repo fine and we don't have ssh access...

Comment: Check for differences with the "others" for which it works. Different connection to the net? Do you have enough space on disk? Local firewall configurations? Same versions of `git` and other stuff that might be involved?

Comment: We ended up reinstalling the repository (we had to do it anyway). Whatever it was - It's gone now...

Answer (score 14):

The error: *RPC failed; result=18, HTTP code = 200* is a libcurl error.

From http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html we can see this is:

> CURLE_PARTIAL_FILE (18)
>
> A file transfer was shorter or larger than expected. This happens when
>   the server first reports an expected transfer size, and then delivers
>   data that doesn't match the previously given size.

You can set GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 before running a command like clone to understand how libcurl is failing.  This might be done in bash with:

```
GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git clone   --progress -v  ...
```

However given the error above you should try adjusting **http.postBuffer**. Try:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```

From here https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html

Comment: That last "magic" line fixed it for me (on Linux using git 1.

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem on Windows machines (cant pull or clone remote repo) while working with git remote server over http (not https) - solution I found to this problem:
On desktop machine (where error occurred) reason for this was an antivirus software (Kaspersky Internet Security 2013 in my case) so I put into exceptions the following git components:

### Exception Rules:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe   | all
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\curl.exe  |all
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Git*  |all
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\git-cheetah*  |all

### Trusted software:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\curl.exe
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe
- c:\program files (x86)\git\libexec\git-core\git-remote-http.exe
- c:\program files (x86)\git\libexec\git-core\git-upload-pack.exe

and tick all options to not interrupt them at all (no tracing of workflow and network activity) - after that the problem was gone away

Comment: We also had Kaspersky on the problematic machine, however (as i recall) disabling it did not solve the problem...