# git bash: error: RPC failed; result = 18, HTP code = 200B | 1KiB/s

Tags: git, clone

When I try to clone on git bash, I receive this error:

```
$git clone <link>
Cloning into 'name_project'...
Password for '<link>':
remote: Counting objects: 100% (659/659), done.
error: RPC failed; result=18, HTTP code = 200B | 1 KiB/s
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: recursion detected in die handler
```

This is the command used:

```
git clone h(double t)ps://account@bitbucket.org/path.git
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 24):

*Solution for failed with error: RPC failed; result=18, HTTP code = 200*

### First Solution:

Try running the command below in the remote repository if error is fatal: index-pack failed

> git repack -a -f -d --window=250 --depth=250

### Second Solution:

Also try the below ones from the remote repository location if the above one didn't work:

> git gc --aggressive
>
> git repack -a -f -d --window=250 --depth=250

### Third Solution:

Try reducing the postBuffer size in the remote repository config.
Follow the steps below

1. Go to remote git repository directory
2. Run the following command to reduce the size of postBuffer

> `git config http.postBuffer 24288000`
>
> you can check this value by doing "git config --get http.postBuffer"
>
> Try cloning the repository now (back to where are you cloning)
>
> If failed with error: RPC failed; result=18, HTTP code = 200 try again by incresing the postBuffer ever further in the config. go to step 1.

Comment: First solution worked for me for the error error: RPC failed; result=18, HTTP code = 200 1.20 MiB/s      
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed

Answer (score 13):

Hey I had same issue but resolved from link i mentioned below

https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=301663284

EDIT:

> ** **From Website:** **
>
> Workaround:
>
> While we have server site settings set appropriately for this option, you may need to adjust/override your client's settings. To do this, execute the following command(s):
>
> From within a specific repository. Note the number at the end is the size, in bytes that you wish to allow in a single post. If you have much larger files, *you may need to increase this number.*
>
> `git config http.postBuffer 524288000`
>
> To set this gloablly for all remote Git repositories you ever connect
>   to
>
> `git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000`

I'm not quite sure that it'll work for everyone, but this solved my problem

Comment: at the time of me having this issue, the link is down. Please provide actual instructions.

Answer (score 7):

I try it and can't solve current solution. It solved when i just visit to my GitLab unicorn log that displays the problem:

```
I, [2014-02-10T17:46:29.953026 #5799]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
E, [2014-02-10T17:47:52.026874 #5719] ERROR -- : worker=1 PID:5728 timeout (181s > 180s), killing
E, [2014-02-10T17:47:52.039670 #5719] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 5728 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=1
```

the worker timeout says about problems with long time running for git clone.

It fixed in GitLab Unicorn config.. just change 180 seconds to bigger in config/unicorn.rb

```
timeout 360
```

If you use other web server or use proxy Nginx, possible you need also:

```
  server {
       ...
    # if a file, which is not found in the root folder is requested,
    # then the proxy pass the request to the upsteam (gitlab unicorn)
    location @gitlab {
      proxy_read_timeout 600; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
      proxy_connect_timeout 600; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
      proxy_redirect     off;

      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;

      proxy_pass http://gitlab;
    }
  }
```

pay attention to part of proxy_read_timeout and proxy_connect_timeout.

Comment: In my case timeout in unicorn.rb was 30 seconds. It looks like stupid message: # nuke workers after 30 seconds instead of 60 seconds (the default). And it was a problem to clone repository because 30 seconds was not enough for big repository. I changed it to 300 and now it works fine.

Comment: @Alex, Thanks a lot..It worked. I was searching for this config file for last 2 days.. +1

Answer (score 4):

We need to adjust/override your client's settings.

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```

Answer (score 2):

**On Linux**

Execute the following in the command line before executing the Git command:

1. export GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1
2. export GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1
3. export GIT_TRACE=1

**On Windows**

Execute the following in the command line before executing the Git command:

1. set GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1
2. set GIT_TRACE=1
3. set GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1

More info ==> [Atlassian Documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/git-clone-fails-error-rpc-failed-result-56-http-code-200-693897332.html)

Answer (score 0):

I faced with this problem using git in Kubuntu. I've also noticed overall instability in networking and found a [solution](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=75770).

> in /etc/resolv.conf
> add the line to the end of the file
>
> options single-request

This fixed delays before every domain name resolution and git started to work like a charm after this.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this Problem while cloning the code from **bitbuket.com**

Error

```
D:\ABCProj>git clone xxxxxxx
cloning into 'xxxxx'.....
Password for 'https://ccccc':
remote:Counting Objects : 14705,done.
remote:Compressing Objects :100%(1234/1234),done.
error:fatal:fatal:RPC failed ; result =18 ,HTTP code =200B/s early EOF
The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal:index-pack failed
```

Solution , below things are fixed my Probs ! Simply I just excute the below any one of the command then could you plz again clone /check out  like

```
D:\ABCProj>git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

If you want To set this **gloablly** for all remote Git repositories you ever connect to

```
D:\ABCProj>git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```

Then Once clone your Project

```
D:\ABCProj>git clone xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Further more details or clarification about this Problem Please refer this site https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=301663284

Answer (score 0):

If the following command not works:

```
git config http.postBuffer 24288000
```

Try this command:

```
git config --add core.compression -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `http.postBuffer`, but still raises the error.

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```

Adding `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` before `git clone ...` works for me.

```
GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git clone https://github.com/...
```

Refer to: [git config - Git clone return result=18 code=200 on a specific repository - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236415/git-clone-return-result-18-code-200-on-a-specific-repository#:%7E:text=The%20error%3A%20RPC%20failed%3B%20result%3D18%2C%20HTTP%20code%20%3D,data%20that%20doesn%27t%20match%20the%20previously%20given%20size.)