# Git clone error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200| 158 KiB/s fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, github

I am just trying to clone my git repo, which I pushed yesterday on my computer:

```
git clone https://github.com/Shiza1aas/islamic
```

The error I am getting is:

> Cloning into 'islamic'...
>   remote: Counting objects: 201, done.
>   remote: Compressing objects: 100% (110/110), done.
>   error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200| 158 KiB/s
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>   fatal: early EOF
>   fatal: index-pack failed

I tried almost every solution I found on the stackoverflow:

[Git clone repository error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26197171/git-clone-repository-error-rpc-failed-result-56-http-code-200)

[git bash: error: RPC failed; result = 18, HTP code = 200B | 1KiB/s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683295/git-bash-error-rpc-failed-result-18-htp-code-200b-1kib-s)

[The remote end hung up unexpectedly while git cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842687/the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-while-git-cloning)

None of the above is working in my case. Please help me to solve this.

Edit 1: When I am downloading the .zip folder from github, and trying to unzip, I am getting some errors:

> Error: /home/khan/Desktop/islamic-master (1).zip: Can not open file as archive
>   Errors: 1

Comment: did you find any solution?. even i have the same problem?

Comment: The issue was with my college internet. They blocked github during the time.