# How can I increase gitlab CE lfs file size limitation as to not get 500 server errors?

Tags: nginx, docker, gitlab, large-files, git-lfs

I'm using the excellent [sameersbn/gitlab](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab) to set up a custom gitlab server for my job.

So I have a ridiculous scenario, I'm using `git lfs` to store files which are in the 10-20 **GB** range, with gitlab ce v8.12.5, but I'm seeing 500 server errors all over the place, my uploads cannot finish.

**Question: Does anyone know how I can increase the server side limitations?**

> Note: This is not a 413 nginx issue, I've set the `client_max_body_size 500G` so it should be forwarding to gitlab just fine.

If any more info is required(i.e. log files, etc) I will gladly provide it, just make a comment.

### Update.1:

There seems to be a related [gitlab issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/22428) on this same problem.

### Update.2

Other resources which are relavant:

For now my hypothesis is that there is a timeout somewhere in the chain or proxy servers in the docker container.

> [git bash: error: RPC failed; result = 18, HTP code = 200B | 1KiB/s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683295/git-bash-error-rpc-failed-result-18-htp-code-200b-1kib-s/21682112#21682112)
>
> https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694

So here's something I just noticed the docker mapped device `/dev/dm-7` becomes **100% full** near the same time that gitlab errors out with a **500**.

Now I'm starting to believe that this is not a gitlab problem, but a docker problem and that gitlab is just running out of space.

Thanks for your time, and cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Problem 1

The first major issue was the following error in `~/log/gitlab-workhorse.log`

`error: handleStoreLfsObject: copy body to tempfile: unexpected EOF`

This error had **nothing** to do with gitlab itself, but rather that docker in their latest version has decided to shrink the default container sizes from 100G / container to 10G / container, which consequently meant that whenever I tried to upload files larger than 10GB, gitlab would attempt to make a **temporary file** of the size of the uploaded file (in my case 30GB) and subsequently blow with the above error message for lack of space in the docker container.

I followed this excellent [guide](http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2016/03/daemon_option_basedevicesize/) on how to increase the size of my container, but it basically boils down to:

```
    sudo `which docker-compose` down
```

to stop the running container.

```
    sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/docker.service
```

and appending

```
    --sotrage-opt dm.basesize=100G
```

as the default size for new base images. Now since there seems to be a current issue with docker, you have to

```
   sudo `which docker` rmi gitlab
```

assuming your image is called `gitlab`, and

```
   sudo `which docker-compose` up
```

to re-pull the image and have it be created with the proper size.

> If this still doesn't work try `sudo systemctl restart docker.service` as this seems to help when docker seems to not do what you asked it to do.

```
    sudo docker exec -it gitlab df -h
```

Should produce something like:

```
Filesystem                                                                                        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/mapper/docker-253:1-927611-353ffe52e1182750efb624c81a3a040d5c054286c6c5b5f709bd587afc92b38f  100G  938M  100G   1% /
```

I'm not 100% certain that all of these settings were necessary, but in solving Problem 2, below, I ended up having to set these as well in the [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab/blob/master/README.md#available-configuration-parameters)

```
    - GITLAB_WORKHORSE_TIMEOUT=60m0s
    - UNICORN_TIMEOUT=3600
    - GITLAB_TIMEOUT=3600
```

## Problem 2

In addition to the resizing the container from 10GB to 100GB I had to add the following to the running instance:

The reason for this was that the filesize was so large (30GB+) and the network speed so slow(10MB/s) that the upload was taking longer than the default nginx and timing out with a `504 Gateway Timeout`.

```
    sudo docker exec -it /bin/bash
```

of the gitlab container's `vim.tiny /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
    http {
    ...
      client_max_body_size 500G;
      proxy_connect_timeout       3600;
      proxy_send_timeout          3600;
      proxy_read_timeout          3600;
      send_timeout                3600;
    ...
    }
```

then I restarted nginx. Sadly `service restart nginx` did not work and I had to:

```
    service stop nginx
    service start nginx
```

> Note: I have a reverse proxy running on this server which catches all http requests, so I'm not certain, but I believe that all the settings that I added to the container's nginx config have to be duplicated on the proxy side

If I've left step out or you would like some clarification on how exactly to do a certain part of the procedure **please** leave a comment and ask. This was a royal pain and I hope to help someone with this solution.