# How to fix this error in git clone

Tags: git, macos

I have tried different methods to install this, but it still does not work. I am trying to clone from github using `git clone https://github.com/CocaPods/Specs.git master`. Please share your ideas. I am using Mac Sierra with 8GB Ram.

[image]

Comment: Did you try again? Perhaps it was a server problem.

Comment: Perhaps a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683295/git-bash-error-rpc-failed-result-18-htp-code-200b-1kib-s)

Comment: yes dear i run it again and again but same error since a couple of week

Comment: Then I would try the solutions from the linke above.

Comment: ok dear i am trying that... thanx

Comment: If you still face problems, update your question accordingly...

Comment: ok dear i will update

Answer (score 0):

This error most likely cause of `low buffer size of git`. Other reason,  `Antivirus or Firewall` could be modifying the HTTP packets.

- Increase the git buffer size:
        `$ git config --global http.postBuffer 2M`
- Disable your `Antivirus or Firewall` for some time and try clone again.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if your problem is cloning or running some command of the project.

to clone try both:

- `git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git`
- `git clone git@github.com:CocoaPods/Specs.git`