# Jenkins `checkout scm` fails with Error code=18 on first invocation, succeeds on second call

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I have been running into an issue where most, but not all, of the jenkins jobs to build our branches are failing, when connecting by proxy, with:

```
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/myorg/myrepo.git 
 > +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=60
 > ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
 > hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress      >      
 > https://github.com/myorg/myrepo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"      >      
 > returned status code 128:
 > stdout: 
 > stderr: error: RPC failed; result=18, HTTP code = 200
 > fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

The Jenkins script that I have, started like so:

```
stage ( "Checkout" ) {
      sh label: "Use proxy to access GitHub", script:
      """
        git config --global http.proxy ${httpProxy}
      """
      scmVars = checkout scm 
      ... ^^ this call wraps the failing `git fetch --tags --progress` call
```

Reading various other stack articles ([git bash: error: RPC failed; result = 18, HTP code = 200B | 1KiB/s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683295/git-bash-error-rpc-failed-result-18-htp-code-200b-1kib-s;) [Git clone return result=18 code=200 on a specific repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236415/git-clone-return-result-18-code-200-on-a-specific-repository) etc), the only thing I have found of note is to increase the postBuffer size. ie. `git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000 # 500mb`

This then looks like:

```
  stage ( "Checkout" ) {
      sh label: "Use proxy to access GitHub", script:
      """
        git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
        git config --global http.proxy ${httpProxy}

      """
      scmVars = checkout scm
      ...
```

This has no net effect. ~90%+ of the builds fail on fetch; ~10% will go through (independent of the branch being built).

This is where affairs become very hard to explain: after hours of banging my head against the wall, I eventually decided to invoke `checkout scm` twice, consecutively; first I call `scm checkout` in a try/catch. The second call, I assign `scmVars`. (nb. if the first call succeeds, the second is idempotent). This looks like:

```
  stage ( "Checkout" ) {
      sh label: "Use proxy to access GitHub", script:
      """
        git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
        git config --global http.proxy ${httpProxy}

      """

      try { 
        checkout scm
      } catch (nil) {
        println "Initial SCM CHECKOUT fails"
      }
      
      scmVars = checkout scm
```

Calling `checkout scm` twice, catching an error on the first call, succeeds every time, in over 50 runs.

**Why?**

- Is `git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000` being applied to both calls or only the second?
- If `http.postBuffer` is only set on the second call, how do I correctly set the property for the first call?
- In broad strokes, what is actually happening here?

*long-time listener, first-time caller; I am not a dev-ops engineer, I just play one on T.V.* - thank you in advance for any and all insights